# Motives based on Hodge cycles vs algebraic cycles

Tags: motives, algebraic-cycles, mixed-hodge-structure

I am not a specialist of motives. I am afraid my questions are rather naive.

We have the category of (pure) motives based on Hodge cycles by Deligne. In his articles with Milne, morphisms between motives are defined using absolute Hodge cycles.
On the the hand we have the (triangulated) category of (mixed) motives based on Voevodsky. His construction is based on algebraic cycle and he used bivariant cycle cohomology, for example.

①How do we see that these categories have related properties?
(At least we know that both categories are rigid tensor)

②Do we construct the derived category of mixed motives based on Hodge cycles?

③To show the equivalence of categories of motives based on algebraic cycles and Hodge cycles do we need the Hodge conjecture stating Hodge cycles are algebraic?

Comment: 2: I don't think so. 3: yes.

Comment: @Mikhail   2. Are Hodge cycles not essential for the construction of the category of mixed motives?
We formulate for the abelian (or triangulated) category of mixed motives an analogous conjecture ‘there is a fully faithful functor from the category of motives to the category of Hodge structures’.
Classically it means that every Hodge cycle is absolute Hodge.
In Andre’s terminology the conjecture implies every Hodge cycle is motivated.
Even though we use algebraic cycles for the construction,
is the conjecture related to only Hodge conjecture, not the motivic t-structure?

Comment: "We formulate for the abelian (or triangulated) category of mixed motives an analogous conjecture ‘there is a fully faithful functor from the category of motives to the category of Hodge structures’" - no, we don't; this should be wrong.